# custom block which includes R in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

In [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/) how can I include R code within a custom block, whereby the R code will be parsed. Like in the example below the r code (plot function) will not be parsed. Is there a way to make this work?

````
```{block2 type='test'}
some text here
plot(1:10)
```
````

Comment: Have you tried to include `r` inside the curly breaks, like ```{r block2 type='test'}

Comment: Thanks but that will make it a regular r code block as far as I can see, which can only contain r code, no text.

Comment: No, this won't work. The only way out as far as I can see is fenced divs: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans but it will be tricky to make them work for non-HTML output (you'll need custom Pandoc filters).

Comment: OK, thanks Yihui Xie, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text references as a hack. This seems to work as long as `valid_markdown` contains a single paragraph/line of markdown.

````
```{r}
valid_markdown <- your_function()
```

(ref:my_hack) `r valid_markdown`

```{block2, type="block"}
(ref:my_hack)

```
````

This hack works fine with text. Getting it work with plots will require a bit more work.